# Change color of Title text in ExpansionTile widget when it is expanded

Tags: flutter

I am using an ExpansionTile and overwriting the default text color when in a collapsed state. I would like to change the color of the title text when the widget is expanded. I noticed that the default behavior if no custom text color is used - is to change the color however as soon as I use a custom color this no longer works. Here is my code.

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
        child: Card(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Text 1',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(112, 190, 115, 1),
                    ),
                  ),
                  children: <Widget>[Text('Text 2'), Text('Text 3')],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the color outside the `build` method first. And then update it using the `onExpansionChanged` event of the `ExpanstionTile`. Like this:

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  Color _textColor = Colors.green;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
        child: Card(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ExpansionTile(
                  onExpansionChanged: (expanded) {
                    setState(() {
                      if (expanded) {
                        _textColor = Colors.blue;
                      } else {
                        _textColor = Colors.green;
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    'Text 1',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: _textColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  children: <Widget>[Text('Text 2'), Text('Text 3')],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly!