# unable to change color of container in expansion Tile flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-container

I am creating an expansion tile in flutter web that I have wrapped around a container. The default is green color. I want to do is so that if the widget is expanded, the color changes to blue. I tried using setState but it still does not work.

```
    Color change = Colors.green;
Container(
                  width: width*0.19,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(

                    color: change,
                    //
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: ExpansionTile(
                    title:  Text('ExpansionTile 2'),
                    subtitle: const Text('Custom expansion arrow icon'),
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 2')),
                    ],
                      onExpansionChanged: (expanded) {
                        setState(() {
                          if (expanded) {
                            change = Colors.blue;
                          } else {
                            change = Colors.green;
                          }
                        });
                      },
                  ),
                ),
```

These are a few links I referred:

[How to change title's text style of ExpansionTile in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72674450/how-to-change-titles-text-style-of-expansiontile-in-flutter)

[Change color of Title text in ExpansionTile widget when it is expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657044/change-color-of-title-text-in-expansiontile-widget-when-it-is-expanded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have added state variable outside the build method in class.

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
      Color change;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Your ContainerWidget()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no issue with your code..Its working okay..
Hope u have placed your code inside stateful not stateless

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Color change = Colors.green;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //backgroundColor: change,
      body:Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(

          color: change,
          //
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: ExpansionTile(
          title:  Text('ExpansionTile 2'),
          subtitle: const Text('Custom expansion arrow icon'),
          children: const <Widget>[
            ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 2')),
          ],
          onExpansionChanged: (expanded) {
            setState(() {
              if (expanded) {
                change = Colors.blue;
              } else {
                change = Colors.green;
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it was in Stateful. The difference was that i put color change inside build